# Grab google user data with AWS amplify Authenticator in react

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, aws-amplify

I am trying to grab Google user data from a simple AWS Cognito hosted UI. My name is displaying when I 'Sign In with Google' but I am unable to access this data after the login screen. In the Enabling Federated Identities section of [AWS Amplify Docs](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/master/docs/media/authentication_guide.md) it recommends I use the `withAuthenticator`. I am able to see the google user signin based on the federated Identity but am unable to see google users in my user pools. So my question, is my configuration setup incorrectly in my user pool or I am not pulling the google user correctly?

[image]

```
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
import { Auth, Authenticator } from 'aws-amplify-react';

const federated = {
  google_client_id: 'XXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com',
};

Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
   identityPoolId: 'us-east-1:XXX',
   region: 'us-east-1', 
   userPoolId: 'us-east-1_XXX'
  },
});

render(
  <div>
    <Authenticator federated={federated}>
      <span>
        Hello
      </span>
   </Authenticator>
  </div>,

  document.getElementById('app'),
);
```

Comment: @KiteCoder mmm that is probably why I am having problems. Thank you

Comment: May not be supported... yet. https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/311 this issue is closed, but I think it is still relevant. There were a couple other issues open too. I was wondering the same thing myself